# Why when i refresh an angular application results to 404 Not Found?

Tags: angular, nginx, kubernetes

I am working on an angular application and deployed it in kubernetes. I can access my application through Nginx Ingress.

I am using angular router to enable navigation through different components in my app.

*Using the deployed application i tried to navigate through different components, when I click refresh on the browser or directly access a specific url path, I get 404 Not Found Page.*

For example, if one accesses URL `mycompany.domain.com`, it shows the home component. In my angular router I have a `/user` path that points to user component.

Upon navigating to user menu, my new URL will now be `mycompany.domain.com/user` - and it is all working as expected.
However if I refresh the current page, it will become 404 Not Found Page, which is the problem.

**My few thoughts:**

1. The router is part of the SPA, and of course will be loaded once the SPA is loaded.
2. The url path `/user` is only known by the router in the SPA - and so when we try to access the mycompany.domain.com/user directly, the server does not find any resource matching to it.
3. The only one who can understand the `/user` url path is my SPA - which is not loaded yet because the server already decided that the resource is not found.

So I concluded (but still to try) the problem can occur anywhere I deploy my SPA regardless my ingress or server configuration.

**My solution** is using angular router `useHash` option - it means that my navigation path will be after a # and be considered as URL Fragments, like this: mycompany.domain.com/#/user, in this case, my server will not try to understand the fragment, as it is meant to be understood by the page. I did so inspired by Vue.js router.

**My questions are:**

1. Is my understanding (and conclusion) correct?
2. Is there any other solution? Because Angular by default doesn't use the hash and I am sure that there is a reason for that because it is not making sense if its doesn't work when deployed?
3. Can URL Rewriting help me? I have tried to look for it myself the usage is not matching with my conclusions.

I am not a SPA expert, I am just starting and I would appreciate if someone will correct and answer me.

Comment: What does your nginx config look like?

Comment: My first guess is that you need to setup redirects in Kubernetes or nginx, and redirect all routes to index.html, then your angular app can take care of the routing. The server doesn't know which file to serve when the route changes unless these redirect rules are in place. I don't know how to set that up on Kubernetes nor nginx though. I think all your assumptions are correct, but I discourage you to use hash routing. Hash routing would work without setting up redirect rules.

Comment: @John, may i know why it is discouraged to use hash routing? I saw that the other routing is called browser routing and need a specific configuration on server for the browser routing be successful.

Comment: @eko, to note, when I mentioned nginx, i am using an nginx ingress controller to exposed my kubernetes application, though I am hosting my angular application on a springboot app using an embedded tomcat server. But the problem is also noticeable when we use an httpd server - we took an httpd server image, copy the dist folder and then run the image - so i could say,  we only use default server configurations.

Comment: Maybe it’s only a personal opinion, but I think it’s more difficult to create support for bots (e.g. To let a third-party app display specific meta data and images based on the url if we share it on SNS or similar.)

Answer (score 1):

**Save This code as web.config then paste the web.config file in the dist folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/index.html" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="/index.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: what kind of configuration is it? will it be understandable by any server? also, it looks to me that we are just redirecting 404 to the /index.html, so in this case, we are losing the url path?

Comment: It’s not a redirect but a rewrite. So if /user is requested, the server should check first if it has a folder or file on the server, if so, serve that, else, serve the contents of index.html

Comment: will it work with any server i deploy my app? and so once it serves the content of the index.html, what will happen to my /user url path?

Comment: I hope it will work in any server. When you reload or refresh the url it will automatically get your /user url path.